# Using Javascript to pass a parameter from a URL to a hidden form field (Gridview)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to pass Hidden Field JobID Value From javaScript

I wasn't to be able to pass and ID such as `3017` from a URL(JobID):

[http://www.company.winrecruit.com/JobDetails.aspx?Key=3017](http://www.company.winrecruit.com/Seeker/Seeker.JobDetails.aspx?Key=6)

Please Help Me ...Sorry for My bad English..

Any ideas much appreciated!

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvJob" CssClass="gvStyle" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    PageSize="15" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvJob_PageIndexChanging">
                                    <PagerStyle CssClass="alphabet-pagination" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S#">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%# gvJob.Rows.Count + 1 + (gvJob.PageIndex * gvJob.PageSize)%>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="Job Title" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostedDate" HeaderText="Posted Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created By" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnStatus" runat="server" CssClass="link" OnClick="lbtnStatus_Click"
                                                    ToolTip="To Change Status" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("JobID") %>'>
                        <img src='images/icons/<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Y" ? "ic-status" : "inactive" %>.png' alt="Status" title="<%# Eval("Status").ToString()== "Y" ? "OPEN" : "CLOSED"%>" />
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnActive" runat="server" CssClass="link" OnClick="lbtnActive_Click"
                                                    ToolTip="To Change Active Status" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("JobID") %>'>
                        <img src='images/icons/<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString() == "Y" ? "ic-status" : "inactive" %>.png' alt="Status" title="<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString()== "Y" ? "ACTIVE" : "INACTIVE"%>" />
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-Width="100">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <a href='Postjob.aspx?Key=<%#Eval("JobID")%>' class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit"
                                                    title="Edit"></a>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" ImageUrl="~/cpanel/images/icons/table/actions-delete.png"
                                                    runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("JobID")%>' OnClick="imgbtnDelete_Click"
                                                    ToolTip="Delete" />
                                                  <%--<a href="http://tellafriend.socialtwist.com:80" class="table-actions-button ic-table-share" title="Share" onclick="return false;" style="vertical-align: baseline;"
                                       ><span class="share" style="border:none;" onmouseout="STTAFFUNC.hideHoverMap(this)" onmouseover="STTAFFUNC.showHoverMap(this, '2010021335271-2', '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString()%>/jobdetail.aspx?Key=<%#Eval("JobID")%>', '<%# Eval("JobTitle") %> - <%# Eval("SkillSet") %>')"
                                            onclick="STTAFFUNC.cw(this, {id:'2010021335271-2', link:'<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString()%>/jobdetail.aspx?Key=<%#Eval("JobID")%>', title: '<%# Eval("JobTitle") %> - <%# Eval("SkillSet") %>' });">
                                            </span></a>--%>
                                               <%-- <a href="http://tellafriend.socialtwist.com:80" title="Share" onclick="return false;" style="vertical-align: baseline;"
                                       ><span class="share" style="border:none;" onmouseout="STTAFFUNC.hideHoverMap(this)" onmouseover="STTAFFUNC.showHoverMap(this, '2010021335271-2', '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString()%>/jobdetail.aspx?Key=<%#Eval("JobID")%>', '<%# Eval("JobTitle") %> - <%# Eval("SkillSet") %>')"
                                            onclick="STTAFFUNC.cw(this, {id:'2010021335271-2', link:'<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString()%>/jobdetail.aspx?Key=<%#Eval("JobID")%>', title: '<%# Eval("JobTitle") %> - <%# Eval("SkillSet") %>' });">
                                            share</span></a>--%>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnJobID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("JobID")%>' />
                                               <a href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString()%>/jobdetail.aspx?Key=<%#Eval("JobID")%>', title: '<%# Eval("JobTitle") %> - <%# Eval("SkillSet") %>" onclick="reply_click(this.id); return false;" class="socialShare" ></a>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

Java Script

How i get `Id` Value

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            var id = document.getElementById('<%= hdnJobID.ClientID %>');

            var url = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString()%>/jobdetail.aspx?Key=' + id + '';

            var options = {

                twitter: {
                    text: 'Check out this awesome jQuery Social Buttons Plugin! ',
                    via: 'Tutorialzine'
                },

                facebook: true,
                googlePlus: true
            };

            $('.socialShare').shareButtons(url, options);
        });

    </script>
```

Thanks

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFGjb.png)

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your posted source code? A reformating removes the horizontal scrollbars and improves the readability. You can doing it by clicking on the "edit" link underneath your question.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
var id = document.getElementById('<%= hdnJobID.ClientID %>');
```

with

```
var id = $("#hdnJobId").val();
```

hope this helps :)

I assume you have jquery ref in your code

Comment: Yes he has , He's using Document Ready Function

Comment: See My Error Image

Comment: Yes Id Value Not passed gridview to javascript @user7417866

Comment: what can i do any idea ?